# WebOS (LG TV): difference between running a hosted web app and opening the same web app in the browser

Tags: webos, smart-tv, widevine, shaka

I have written a web app for DRM protected playback, using Shaka Player,
and I am wondering if I can have testers simply  open it in the browser, without me having to package it,
and them having to install it.
My guess is that since the hosted app runs in the same chromium web engine the browser uses,
there is no difference apart from profile related stuff, local storage clearing, etc.
which are not important to me.
Am I wrong?

Comment: If you run your app on browser, remote will work as mouse pointer. You will not be able to navigate using arrow keys like you do inside the app.

Comment: I got the same issue. The shaka-player works perfectly when I'm testing it on Chrome, but not on Safari and LG WebOS. As I investigate further, it seems the promise created by shaka.Player.load(assetUri) is being rejected while in Safari, but succeeds when tested in Chrome.

Comment: In newer TVs there is an option "Add to launcher" in browser. This will make the webpage load as an app and you can navigate using 5 direction keys